# How does it work comparing/matching images with kd-trees and nearest neighbor search?

Tags: computational-geometry, nearest-neighbor, sift, kdtree

I have been querying google for some material about kd-trees and image comparison but I couldn't make the 'link' between the technics for image comparison using kd-trees.
Firstly, I found some articles talking about speed improvement with randomized kd-trees, then I was introduced to SIFT. After understanding basically how SIFT works, I read about nearest neighbor search.

My real question is: If I have a mesh of points from SIFT, then I create the kd-tree for every image. How the nearest neighbor search can help me compare the images? At first, I thought that comparing images with a tree would work with some algorithm checking the tree structure and how near every point is from an image A from a point in the same node in and image B.

If the question is too dumb, please suggest material or some topic for search.

Thank you!

Comment: I'm at the same point that you respecting kdtree, sift, surf.. etc, I think that we can get in touch using Google Talk, or anything else and speak about that. Contact me at: http://codepad.org/TmazIhsY :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd suggest first understanding slow feature matching, without kdtrees.

- input: 1000 reference features, e.g. of faces or flowers; call these F1 .. F1000
- a query feature Q: which face or flower feature is most like, nearest, Q ?

As you know,
[SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform)
reduces an image feature to 128 8-bit numbers, scaled so that
  similarity( feature F, feature Q ) =
Euclidean distance( SIFT(F), SIFT(Q) ).

The simplest way to find which of F1 .. F1000 is most like Q
is just to look at F1, F2 ... one by one:

```
# find the feature of F1 .. F1000 nearest Q
nearestdistance = infinity
nearestindex = 0
for j in 1 .. 1000:
    distance = Euclideandistance( SIFT(Fj), SIFT(Q) )  # 128 numbers vs. 128 numbers
    if distance < nearestdistance:
        nearestdistance = distance
        nearestindex = j
```

(Of course one computes the SIFT numbers outside the loop.)

A [Kdtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kdtree)
is just a way of finding nearby vectors quickly;
it has little to do with *what* is being matched
(vectors of numbers representing ...), or *how* (Euclidean distance).
Now kdtrees are very fast for 2d, 3d ... up to perhaps 20d,
but may be no faster than a linear scan of all the data above 20d.
So how can a kdtree work for features in 128d ?
The main trick is to quit searching early.
The paper by Muja and Lowe, 
[Fast approximate nearest neighbors with automatic algorithm configuration](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.160.1721&rep=rep1&type),
2009, 10p, describes multiple randomized kdtrees for matching 128d SIFT features.
(Lowe is the inventor of SIFT.)

To compare two images I and Q, one finds a set of feature vectors --
several hundred up to a few thousand SIFT vectors -- for each,
and looks for near matches of these sets.
(One may think of images as molecules, features as atoms;
near-matching molecules is *much* harder than near-matching atoms,
but it helps to be able to match atoms quickly.)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on using kd-trees for approximate NN search in higher dimensions, you might want to review the experiments here: http://zach.in.tu-clausthal.de/software/approximate_nn/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to extract color code values of each image and create a KD tree using those features vectors.

You can use the following mat lab code to extract the color code features.

```
im = imread('image.jpg');

len = size(im,3);
if(len == 1)
    im = ind2rgb(im, colourMap);
    im = uint8(im.*255);
end

im(logical(  0 <= im & im <=  63)) = 0;
im(logical( 64 <= im & im <= 127)) = 1;
im(logical(128 <= im & im <= 191)) = 2;
im(logical(192 <= im & im <= 255)) = 3;
im = im(:,:,1) * 16 + im(:,:,2) * 4 + im(:,:,3);

imHist = histc(im(:),0:63);
```